# How to find OBS Studio recording where the recording was paused and resumed programmatically?

Tags: video-processing, video-capture, mkv, obs

I would like to programmatically find where the video was paused and resumed during the entire recording.

I have a screen recording by OBS studio which is over 7 hours and it has many pause and resume. So I want to programmatically find times / frames / location of this pauses and resumes.

The file type is MKV

Comment: good luck with that. in principle, it can be impossible to tell. the act itself may leave some traces (or not).  how deep are you willing to go down the rabbit hole? -- what's in the video? can you see a clock or anything?

Comment: I have captured my programming session. it is about 8 hours and i want to cut pauses resumes and some unwanted resumes. since it is too big i would like to find pauses and resumes in the video automatically to make my job easier and not miss anything @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: I know but *can you see a clock or anything?* -- in the future may I suggest that you don't pause the recording but instead mark those points in the video so you can easily see them while editing. a loud (enough) clap is easy to see in a waveform display.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments I don't think this will be straightforward unless you have some clock points etc.

You could use a video analysis solution to go trough the frame by frame - it will be processing intensive but may meet your needs.

For example, using openCV you could read in the video frame by frame and compare each frame with it's predecessor, identifying groups of frames which are mostly the same (assuming your video frames are all more or less the same when you are paused).

If the video includes some sort of play or pause button on the screen when it paused you could also use OpenCv to detect this.